# Page anchor URL display

Tags: html, anchor

Is there a way to set what an anchor tag displays in the URL?

For instance, if I was to write:

```
<a id="HomeAnchor"></a>
```

Linking to it would lead to the page:

```
www.example.com#HomeAnchor
```

While there's nothing wrong with this normally, the site is relatively large and and to keep from any conflicts the ID's are reasonably long and descriptive. Basically, they're not really something you'd want to show to the customers.

Is there a way to make a complex ID anchor produce a non-complex URL? Purely for aesthetic/user experience purposes e.g.

```
<a id="FeaturesPageTopAnchor"></a>
```

to

```
www.example.com#Top
```

Ideally I'd like to avoid modifying the URL with JS if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"reasonably long and descriptive" That sounds like something you *do* want to show to the customer. I'd rather have that they see `example.com/products/MyAwesomeProduct#FeaturesAndInstallation` 
than 
`example.com/products/160#EFXXKgg7`.

Apart from that, there is no need to make anchors unique on the entire site, only per page. So the `#Top` anchor can be named `Top` on every page.

And you can shorten the name without leaving out information too. It is the web, so you are viewing a page. And you're jumping to an anchor (what else), so you can just name it `FeaturesHome` instead of `FeaturesPageHomeAnchor` and it will still be the same anchor, with almost as little risk of having any name collisions.

Note that it doesn't have to be an `a` element at all. You can just anchor to any id of any element.

The anchor itself is what you see is what you get. The value in the url is used to search for an id. No workarounds for that in HTML. Maybe you can work around it with JavaScript trickery, but it will be complex, error prone and basically not worth it.